# Что делать если async def on_message(message) не работает?

Tags: python, discord

**

### Добрый вечер! с наступающим новым годом.

**

**Я написал `async def on_message(message)`, наверняка уже все поняли, для чего оно. Я его написал чтобы когда человек писал пункт, ему отправлялось значение этого пункта. В моем случае правила. Пример:**

> 1.1
> Запрещено рекламировать посторонние проекты.

**Затем я начал писать следующие команды для бота, сегодня я решил проверить команды, но бот не отвечает на вопрос. И самое интересное, то что никаких ошибок не было. Я буду крайне благодарен, если вы мне поможете, скажу сразу, я совсем новичок и многое пока что я не понимаю.**

Код:

````
async def on_message(message):
    if '1.1' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено рекламировать посторонние Discord сервера без согласии администрации.```')
    if '1.2' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено использовать другую учетную запись чтобы избежать наказаниe.```')
    if '1.3' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено распространять личную информацию участников сервера.```')
    if '1.4' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещен флуд/спам во всех каналах кроме #flood. Также запрещено использовать капс.```')
    if '1.5' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено "тегать" роли сервера/саппортов/администраторов без смысловой нагрузки.```')
    if '1.6' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено всячески оскорблять участников сервера(вне) а также оскорблять родных.```')
    if '1.7' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено разжигание национальной розни, дискриминация, враждебность к религиям и людям с ограниченными возможностями.```')
    if '1.8' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещена пропаганда наркотиков также терроризма либо материал содержащий сексуальный характер.```')
    if '1.9' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещена неконструктивная критика по отношению к серверу, призыв покинуть сервер, критика к администрации либо оскорбление самого сервера.```')
    if '2.0' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено использовать музыкальные команды во всех каналах кроме #❍commands-dj.```')
    if '2.1' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено использовать посторонние ПО для изменение своего голоса.```')
    if '2.2' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено использовать ненастроенный микрофон, перед тем как вы зашли на сервер и хотите общаться, удостоверьтесь, правильно ли настроен ваш микрофон.```')
    if '2.3' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено намеренное усиление чувствительности своего микрофона с помощью посторонних ПО/усиление чувствительности дБ ради вреда других участников.```')
    if '2.4' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('```· Запрещено флудить словами в голосовых категориях т.е всячески мешать геймплею.```')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
````

Comment: Потому что над функцией должен быть хендлер, а так функция просто никогда не вызывается

Comment: @ClarkDevlin как должен выглядеть хендлер? либо скиньте ссылку. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что за бот? Какую библиотеку используете?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin я пишу бота для дискорд сервера, он будет функционировать как модерирующий и не только. Пишу бота на питоне, библиотеки следующие: 
```aiodns
aiohttp
async-timeout
attrs
cchardet
cff
chardet
discord.py
idna
multidict
pycares
pycparser
typing_extensions
yarl```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/